# Deployed Web Core API: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have deployed a new application that contains a Web Project which communicates with a Web Core API.
I have used this link as a reference to set it up;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis
IIS has been set up for a while on this test server, so some the steps did not need to be repeated.
In IIS if I browse the Web API is launches as follows.
[image]
But if I do likewise for the web project that uses it, I am getting this error:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found) for a simple get call to the Web API.
```

What should I be considering to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the URI I needed on the deployment server needed to have the name of my application, whilst in development this was not needed. Once I made that correction it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple possibilities I see

- You just browsed to the root url and you do not have any [default page setup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615(v=ws.10).aspx) in IIS . To see the Web API,browse to the webapi url you have specified in your route.config file.

Default route will be like this based on your [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing).Could you browse to

`http://testweb.sherrygreengrp.com/api/<controller>`

- You do not have the Windows Server Hosting Bundle

> Install the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle on the hosting
>   system. The bundle will install the .NET Core Runtime, .NET Core
>   Library, and the ASP.NET Core Module. The module creates the
>   reverse-proxy between IIS and the Kestrel server. Note: If the system
>   doesn't have an Internet connection, obtain and install the Microsoft
>   Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable before installing the .NET Core
>   Windows Server Hosting bundle

- [ASP.NET CORE Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/aspnet-core-module) correctly configured .Do you have this setting in your web.config

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" 
          arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
          stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
          stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>`

Comment: OK so this is interesting. Originally there was a web.config downloaded very similar to the one you have posted here. However this stopped me from browsing the project from IIS, so I renamed it to webx.configx and then I could. On your advice I rename it back again to web.config and when I launch it I get "This webpage cannot be found". In Postman when I make the call I get a 404, and when I launch the web project that uses the web api I get "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it "

Comment: It may be an issue that the Web API project is a Core Project, whilst the other projects that it uses are not Core projects.

Comment: "This webpage cannot be found" is basically 404 and this is because AspNetCoreModule is not hooked up correctly.Have you followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module) for ANCM